# MySQL: Join tables by DATETIME intervals

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, join

I have this 4 tables:

drivers

```
(id, name)
```

vehicles

```
(id, license_plate)
```

itineraries (point to point journey)

```
(id, vehicle_id, starting_datetime, ending_datetime)
```

driver_working_periods

```
(id, driver_id, vehicle_id, starting_datetime, ending_datetime)
```

Basically I have to get all `itineraries` for a specific driver based on the `starting_datetime` and `ending_datetime`.

The only way I managed to do this is doing a `foreach` loop on the `driving_working_periods` results and every time query the `itineraries` table and find which one matches the `datetime` intervals as well as the `vehicle_id`.

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this in one query because there are 1000+ rows in each table and every week it will grow bigger.

Thank you.

Comment: Which table `starting_datetime` and `ending_datetime` you want to use? Do you mind to add dummy table content and expected result?

Comment: I need to use the datetimes from the working_periods table and find all itineraries that are in that interval. I am adjusting @Shakil anwer and it seems to work great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `itineraries` a
INNER JOIN `driver_working_periods` b
ON `a`.`vehicle_id` = `b`.`vehicle_id`
AND  (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `a`.`starting_datetime`, `a`.`ending_datetime`)) = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `b`.`starting_datetime`, `b`.`ending_datetime`))
```

Comment: With a few adjustments your answer works great. Thank you very much.  Would you mind explaining it because I don't understand very well what's going on

Comment: If you would not faliliar with sql join, give it a try. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins. it may be helpful.